# Does this function work in conjunction properly with JTable model?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a program that is written to work in conjunction with a JTable and a few other Swing elements in order to display and model a backend for a game. The function is supposed to get the first row selected and the last row selected and store them in an array rows at index 0 and 1 respectively. Thanks for your help and hope to understand what is going on here.

```
    public int[] getRows(JTable table) {    
    rows = new int [2];
    rows[0] = table.getSelectedRow();
    rowCount = table.getSelectedRowCount() - 1;
    rows[1] = rows[0] + rowCount;
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?  What happens if no rows are selected? What happens if there are no rows?  What happens if there are gaps of unselected rows between the selected rows?

Comment: Is there anything wrong about my function or if there is a selection in the JTable will this method properly return the values in the rows[] array?

Comment: Did you test your method to see how it behaves? This site is not a very good substitute for your trusty Java compiler and JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JTable.getSelectedRows()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows%28%29) can you help you in this case. Just take the first and last index from the array it returns. Note that it can return an empty array.